# merging two dataframes based on values in a column

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I'm trying to merge two dataframes:

- df1 (`data`): has data for multiple individuals, one column specifies the location (`Location`) where the individual (`Bird`)was found. Therefore there exist multiple rows with the same location name (fe. Ijzermonding_slikken).
  [image: data]
- df2 (`clean_lonlat`): has the same location names as df1, but also includes the coordinates (`lonlat$WKT`) from this exact location (`clean_naam`). There only exists one row per location with coordinates (see again Ijzermonding_slikken).

  [image]

I want to merge the two datasets so that in df1 the coordinates corresponding to each location (taken out of df2) are included.

I've come up with this codeline:

```
data.coordinates <- merge(data, clean_lonlat, by.x="Location", by.y="clean_naam",all.x=TRUE)
```

However, if I try this I get as output a lot of NA's in the coordinates column because the number of rows in each dataframe are not equal, and the code only provides the first `Location` with the corresponding coordinates. Is there a way to add coordinates to each location?

Comment: That `merge()` looks correct. Are you sure that set of unique values in both `data$Location` and `clean_lonlat$clean_naam`are identical? I.e. there's no trailing whitespace in one or another?

Answer (score 0):

could you try the left join

```r
data.coordinates <- data %>% left_join(clean_lonlat, by=c("Location"="clean_naam"))
```